# How to setup the keyboard if l'am using two text fields

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I've been trying to set up my keyboard since a few days ago, but I can't manage to do it. I just want the `imageView` to move up when I am writing in the bottom text field. In fact, it's working, but it also moves up when I try to write at the `topTextField`. I don't want that, because when that happens, I can't see the `textField` at the top, and I can't see what I'm writing.

I'll include my screenshots and my code.

In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF0mE.jpg), I pressed the `topTextField` to write something, but as you can see, the `topTextField` is lost. I mean the view moves up when I press the `topTextField` and I don't want that. What I want is so that when I press the `topTextField` the keyboard should appear but the view should be at the same place.

And in [the last one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Yw6.jpg) I pressed the `textFieldBottom`, and as you can see, it works. The view moves up so I can see what I'm writing inside the `textFieldBottom`.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
self.subscribeToKeyboardNotificationsDown()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.unsubscribeToKeyBoardNotifications()
    self.unsubscribeToKeyBoardNotificationsDown()
}
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)) , name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
func unsubscribeToKeyBoardNotifications() {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}
func subscribeToKeyboardNotificationsDown() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,  object: nil)
}

func unsubscribeToKeyBoardNotificationsDown() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.frame.origin.y += getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}

func getKeyboardHeight(notification:NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @XamuelSchulman is swift language (IOS)

Answer (score 0):

// do one thing maintain one globle varible to save current textfield which is on editing mode based on that varible u put condition to move imageview
following example code will help you.

```
var currentTextField: UITextField

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   currentTextField = textField
   return true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
     if currentTextField == textFieldBottom {
       view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When topTextField becomes first responder, you're changing view.frame.origin, this is moving your topTextField up. Instead of changing view frame, you can set constraints for bottomTextField and you can change constraints for bottomTextField programmatically in keyboardWillShow method. This way your view frame will not change and topTextField will not move up.